# How was this killing scene filmed?

Tags: editing

In this scene, at 5:00, you can see two people in frame and one of them shoots the other guy in the head using a shotgun. How did they edit it to look like one continuous scene? I'd imagine they would have to shoot the scene twice, once without makeup and blood, and once with makeup and blood. But how do they add these two clips together to make it look like one scene?

Comment: Are you asking how they did this one scene? Because there are MANY ways of shooting a "killing scene," and list questions are frowned upon here.

Comment: The edits are pretty obvious in the clip in the question.

Comment: @meat trademark yes I'm trying to find out how it was filmed and edited but made to look like one scene.

Comment: @todd wilcox How was it done?

Comment: Looks to be edited on the digital explosion (should have been smaller muzzle flare, imo), with digital blood mist, practical & digital blood on face as primary elements. To shoot the scene, have the actors freeze right when the gun would fire. Quickly (you want the actors to move as little as possible) apply some blood and continue shooting the scene as normal. Now edit out the part where the blood was applied. Voila! (Not posted as answer because I'm not 100% sure about this and not sure if I explained it well enough. Seems simple to me on this end of my comment.)

Comment: The question reads almost like sarcasm, given how much changes between the muzzle flash frame and the next frame: victim's head rotates left, camera jolts upwards, gunman's body snaps upright (opposite to recoil), gunman's mouth snaps shut. And the muzzle flash effect is poorly masked, since it brightens not just the victim's shoulders but also the brick wall in his background.

Comment: Maybe it's...simply just a crappy YouTube video.

Comment: Ugh. I hate this, but here it goes: I hope this wasn't just an excuse by one the people involved to gets eyes and clicks. To be sure, the video is annoying and of very poor quality.